# How to set fixed position in same/current one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the code below. That is part in my modal implementation. Its like when I open modal it should display empty vertical scrollbar at the right side.

The scrollbar were working fine in these code below. My only problem is when I open modal it automatically scrolls at the top.

My question, how to use fixed position that does not scrolls automatically at the top (stays at the same position).

---

```
const scrollY = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--scroll-y'); 
body.style.position = 'fixed';
body.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
```

I tried these as solution, but it doesn't work at all.

```
body.style.bottom= `-${scrollY}`; // solution1
body.style.bottom= 0; // solution2
```

Or even no `body.style.[position]` it still scrolls at the top.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/escbooster12/pen/bGWBvrz

Comment: could you upload a jsfiddle or similar with the code?

Comment: @MartinGainzaKoulaksezian i added codepen.

Comment: _Code_. Singular. "Codes" is like "rices" (or nuclear launch codes). :)

Comment: Your Codepen isn't working for me but an <a> with href="#" will link you to the top of the page. Instead use a <div> or <button> and use "cursor: pointer;" if you want the hand on hover.